# Using await on HttpClient in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, httpclient

I just following a sample in calling HttpClient in sync mode, it works fine in a Console application.

However, when I move it to a wpf application, the program hanged without any return.

I try to isolate the problem by building a separate class to handle a dummy request to visit www.google.com.

It seems that the application hang in calling client.GetAsync, may I know if there has any thing need to be changed from console application to wpf in this case?

Please find the source of both the console application and wpf as below,

Console application - works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ca03
{
    static class action
    {
        static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync()
        {
            // ... Target page.
            string page = "http://www.google.com/";

            // ... Use HttpClient.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                // ... Read the string.
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // ... Display the result.
                if (result != null &&
                result.Length >= 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static string goDownload()
        {
            Task<string> x = DownloadPageAsync();
            string result = x.Result;
            return result;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = action.goDownload();
            Console.WriteLine(data);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

WPF application: (just a plain project with a button added) - hang in GetAsync

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace wpf02
{

    static class action
    {
        static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync()
        {
            // ... Target page.
            string page = "http://www.google.com/";

            // ... Use HttpClient.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                // ... Read the string.
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static string goDownload()
        {
            Task<string> x = DownloadPageAsync();
            string result = x.Result;
            return result;
        }

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string data = action.goDownload();
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I go into this problem in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
string result = x.Result;
```

When you use the `Result` property, that blocks the current thread until the task has completed. That's a problem when your continuations are meant to run on the same thread...

Basically, there's no point in your `goDownload` method - just change your `DownloadPageAsync` method to be public, then change your `button_Click` method to *also* be async so you can await the result:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = await action.DownloadPageAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It works fine if I modify the code as your suggestion.
However, this is the structure of my existing application, the class action is in fact comes from a separate library project, and I want to simplify the caller's code by getting a string directly from this method.  
And in my application, goDownload will be called from a background thread which is fired by the timer event.  
Is there any way to build a utility function like goDownload as above, so that the caller can just use this method to receive a string directly without adding async/await.

Comment: @James: You'd basically have to put the whole thing into a background thread, if you want a blocking call. But fundamentally you're calling the method from the UI thread at the moment - and you really shouldn't block the UI thread for network operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just try to simplify the case using the example above, so it's calling from button click of UI thread.  
I just find another example, it seems that if I got the result directly from GetAcync(page).Result, it will be executed in sync mode.  But I don;t know if it works under a background thread.  I will modify my project to test it.

Comment: Although this is not exactly my requirement, but I got some idea from your solution to solve my problem.  So I close this question with your suggestion.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Top-level reason of this - WPF ( as any UI app) have a UI-thread, that work with winwdows loop queue. Jon Skeet give you a simplest desigion, but you can use thread from CLR ThreadPool:

```
            Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => DownloadPageAsync());
        string result =  = await t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Although this is not exactly which I'm looking for, but it give me the idea to making the required function in different approach, and I learnt more about the WPF UI thread now.